# Find the​ B-coordinate vector of x (matrix)

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

My vector $x$ is in a subspace $H$ with a basis $B = \{b1,b2\}$.

```
b1 = [ 5]      b2 = [-1]        x = [ 5]
     [-9]           [ 3]            [-3]
```

I need to find the​ **B-coordinate** vector of $x$.

I found out it is:

```
B-coordinate = [c1]
               [c2]
```

Where

```
[ 5] = c1[ 5] + c2[ -1]
[-3]     [-9]     [  3]
```

Problem is I don't know how to solve for **c1** and **c2** in such an equation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pull the factors c1 and c2 into your vectors. Then you get a simple linear system with 2 equations and two unknowns (c1 and c2).

Comment: Like so: **(5)c1 - (1)c2 = 5** AND **(-9)c1 + (3)c2 = -3**  ?

Comment: ok i got it thanks allot

Comment: Exactly. If you found that answer helpful, vote for it and check it as done, please.